# apache2 multiple instances under www-data

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi, gnu

I am running apache2 on my RaspberryPi, mainly to interface with an mpd php client for streaming audio. After a month or so, I see the following:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                     
 1496 www-data  20   0 55900  17m 2112 S   0.0  9.3   0:30.32 apache2                                                                     
 7198 www-data  20   0 54868  15m 2188 S   0.0  8.4   0:10.57 apache2                                                                     
 7182 www-data  20   0 54868  15m 2168 S   0.0  8.3   0:11.67 apache2                                                                     
 1497 www-data  20   0 53844  15m 2132 S   0.0  8.2   0:07.58 apache2                                                                     
 2609 mysql     20   0  314m  15m  280 S   0.7  8.1  71:58.52 mysqld                                                                      
 7185 www-data  20   0 54868  14m 2180 S   0.0  8.1   0:08.71 apache2                                                                     
 7183 www-data  20   0 54868  14m 2120 S   0.0  8.1   0:14.36 apache2                                                                     
 1499 www-data  20   0 53844  14m 2144 S   0.0  8.0   0:07.73 apache2                                                                     
 1932 mpd       20   0 81204 8152  584 S   0.0  4.3 145:46.25 mpd                                                                         
 7211 www-data  20   0 45652 8004 2204 S   0.0  4.2   0:01.65 apache2                                                                     
 3318 www-data  20   0 45652 7944 2140 S   0.0  4.2   0:03.43 apache2                                                                     
 7210 www-data  20   0 45652 7784 2176 S   0.0  4.1   0:01.28 apache2                                                                     
 1965 root      20   0 44532 5268  216 S   0.0  2.8   1:53.06 apache2
 7168 www-data  20   0 45652 7956 2140 S   0.0  4.2   0:02.42 apache2
```

Along with mpd and mysql, and the root apache2 process, 11 apache2 process running as www-data. On reboot, I see 5 apache2 processes under www-data.

Why are more processes spawnded, and not closed down? I continue to see this grow until there are 20+ processes, which slows down the something this small with limited resources.

Why are new processes spawned, then persist? Can I control this in conf.d (I have tried, but the feedback process takes a few days or week, so it's hard to tell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache - when running in pre-fork mode - spawns a pool of worker processes in order to keep the response time low. Every worker will be responsible for a certain request. So, if there are 11 workers running, apache could serve 11 requests in "parallel" without spawning a new process (what would take a significant amount of time)

Apache spawns that workers / and keeps them alive intelligently, but you can set the maximum and minimum amount of workers in the `apache2.conf`

Comment: OK - it looks like I need to set `MinSpareThreads` and `MaxSpareThreads`. I just set them to 5, 8, repsectively (I have very little traffic), and I'll see how that works.